# Assign value directly to class variable

Tags: c#

I don't know if this is that easy nobody is looking for that, but I didn't found anything...

I want to do the following:

```
public class foo
{
    string X 
    {
        get; 
        set
        { 
            //set and do some other stuff 
        }
    }

    //some other functions
}
```

Main:

```
private foo = new foo();

foo = "bla";
```

How can I assign this `bla` DIRECTLY to the class-variable `foo` without using `foo.X = "bla"`?

How are the datatypes doing this, e.g string? 
How are they made?
Because I can do `string y; y = "abc"` ?

Comment: You will have to override assignment operator `=`. But why you want to do that?

Comment: String can do it because `"abc"` *is* a string. Just like you can assign object of type X into a variable of type X.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Never thought about it, this absolutely makes sense....

Comment: Note that the `private` there makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Are you looking for *implicit operator*?

```
public class foo {
  string X {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public static implicit operator foo(string value) {
    return new foo() {
      X = value
    };
  }
}
```

Please, notice, that there's no constructor call here
which will be called (and thus create a new foo instance) implicitly:

```
private foo myFoo = "bla";
```

Comment: Note that this creates a *new* `foo` instance and the assignment completely replaces the old object. The old object in particular has no way of knowing that it is being replaced that way.

Answer (score -2):

I think you meant:

```
private foo = new foo();
foo.X = "bla";
```

Not? 
So this will be:

```
private foo = new foo() {
    X = "bla"
};
```

And X needs to be public. 
Did I understand you right?

Comment: This is exactly what the OP *did not* mean.